# The usage of "para" and "a" with places

Tags: gramática, preposições

> Eu vou para o parque
>
> Eu vou a Portugal nas férias.
>
> Eu vou a Angola.

When is para used with and without an article? Does it vary from region to region where "a" is often used than "para" ?

Comment: Duplicate, though the answers in the answer linked are IMO weak, or at least focused on usage in Brasil. I'll see if I can do something about it. Meanwhile, the corresponding [section](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/ffdeb8361ca1c122fef08721cc7af0cc) in  «Gramática do Português» from the Gulbenkian Foundation.

Comment: In case the user can't read Portuguese  "Ir a" implies a being temporary (like passing through) and "ir para" means a more permanent or change implies staying somewhere